# InputStream being lost

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a class titled: ServiceCaller.java

This class contains a method used to call web services:

```
public static Response callService(String strURL, String Token, int timeout, Boolean isPostMethod) {

    String error = "";
    int statusCode = HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);

        // Allow non trusted ssl certificates
        if(strURL.startsWith("https"))
        {               
            TrustManagerManipulator.allowAllSSL();
        }

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (isPostMethod) {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }
        else {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        // Allow Inputs                                                     
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);                                              

        // Allow Outputs                                                    
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                                             

        // Don't use a cached copy.                                         
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);       

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");                

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");     

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Token", Helpers.getUTF8Encode(Token));

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);   

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        Response r = new Response(statusCode, urlConnection.getInputStream(), "No Exception");

        return r;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        error = ex.getMessage();

        if (error != null && !error.equals("") && error.contains("401"))
            statusCode = HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED;

    } finally {

        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }

    return new Response(statusCode, null, error);

}
```

Here's the Response class:

```
public static class Response
{
    private int statusCode;
    private InputStream responseStream;
    private String exception;

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public InputStream getResponseStream() {
        return responseStream;
    }

    public String getExceptionError() {
        return exception;
    }

    public Response(int code, InputStream stream, String strException)
    {
        this.statusCode = code;
        this.responseStream = stream;
        this.exception = strException;
    }
}
```

This is the Test class that I use to test the function in ServiceCaller:

```
    public class TestDemo {

        private static final String EncriptionKey = "keyValueToUse";

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {

                String strURL = "http://...";
                String strURL2 = "http://...";
                String Token = "iTcakW5...";
                int timeout = 120000;
                Boolean isPostMethod = true;

                ServiceCaller.Response resp = ServiceCaller.CallService(strURL2, Token, timeout, isPostMethod);

                InputStream inputStream = resp.getResponseStream();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
                String resultJSON = writer.toString();

                System.out.println("Status Code: " + resp.getStatusCode());
                System.out.println("JSON String:\n" + resultJSON);
                System.out.println("Exception: " + resp.getExceptionError());

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the Output of executing hte previous code:

---

```
Status Code: 200
JSON String:

Exception: No Exception
```

---

Here's the problem, the InputString that is returned in the Test class appears to be empty because the conversion to string returns an empty string BUT if I do the same code to convert the InputString inside the CallService function then the conversion is successful, also note that the Status Code and Exception (strings) are being returned correctly.

Comment: try-catch-finally construction? or a try-with-resource construction? inside the CallService method.

Comment: What happens to the HttpURLConnection

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I have updated my post and included the full code.

Comment: @dkatzel I have updated my post and included the full code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Response CallService(String strURL, String Token, int timeout, Boolean isPostMethod) {

     HttpURLConnection urlConnection = ...

     ...

     new Response(statusCode, urlConnection.getInputStream(), "No Exception");
}
```

This code missing in the ... is probably the most important part. I guess you are closing the HttpURLConnection before returning back to the caller. How you do this can vary:

- You simply close it before the `return`
- try-catch-finally: You are closing it in the finally block.
- you are using a `try-with-resource` construction as introduced in Java 7. The HttpURLConnection might be getting closed automatically. This is more unlikely since HttpURLConnection does not implement AutoClosable.

Comment: That would throw `IOException stream is closed`. `HttpURLConnection` is not `AutoClosable`.

Comment: That was what I was thinking as well. But the OP hided a lot of code in several places. Maybe there is somewhere a try-catch block where the catched Exception is not reported.

Comment: That's more likely for sure.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I have updated my post and included the full code and you're right about one thign I did close the connection in the finally block but even if I removed that the problem still persits the InputString appears to be empty when is returned by the CallService function.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved by first getting the InputStream from HttpURLConnection, then converting it to a byte array, then putting that byte array into a ByteArrayInputStream

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(urlConnection.getInputStream());
ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

return new Response(statusCode, byteStream, "");
```

According to the documentation a ByteArrayInputStream:

> public ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] buf) Creates a ByteArrayInputStream
>   so that it uses buf as its buffer array. The buffer array is not
>   copied. The initial value of pos is 0 and the initial value of count
>   is the length of buf. Parameters: buf - the input buffer.

Comment: Note that `toByteArray()` reads bytes in the same way `copy()` does so this does not explain the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I'm still using copy() in the Test class to convert the returned InputStream(ByteArrayInputStream) into a string using StringWriter, the only thing that has changed now is that instead of returning an InputStream I return a ByteArrayIputStream I'm not entirely sure why this works but my guess is because the ByteArrayInputStream "contains an internal buffer that contains bytes that may be read from the stream"

Comment: No that isn't relevant. You're doing the same thing now as using `copy` with a `StringWriter` in your `callService` method.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I used the copy method of IOUtils with StringWriter in my Test class not in callService, I think it's relevant because if I return the InputStream directly and use the copy method in my Test class the StringWriter instance was empty but when I returned a ByteArrayInputStream instead and then used the copy method in my Test class the StreamWriter instance was filled with the resulting JSON string, again I'm not entirely sure why it works but it works now, before it returned an empty stream now it's not empty.

Comment: You are currently reading the `connection.getInputStream()` in your `callService` method and putting the bytes into a `ByteArrayInputStream`. Previously you had copied the `connection.getInputStream()` into a `StringWriter` in the `callService` method and that had also worked. It fails when you do that outside the method. That should not be the case under any circumstances and I'm almost convinced your program just wasn't clean.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I cleaned the program, I even created a new Java application and moved those classes and still got the same results, you can try it for yourself and see.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Well then I'm not sure because I cleaned the project, created a new project and still got the same results, so I don't know how you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are already consuming the `InputStream` in your `CallService` method

```
statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
Response resp = new Response(statusCode, urlConnection.getInputStream(), "");
InputStream inputStream = resp.getResponseStream();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer); // consuming the stream
String resultJSON = writer.toString(); // you never use this, so why is it here?
```

So when you try to read from it again in `main()` there are no bytes left.

You can only read bytes from it once.

This doesn't throw any exceptions because `IOUtils` simply calls `InputStream#read(...)` which returns `-1` if the EOF has been reached.

---

Note that Java naming convention states that method names should start with a lowercase character.

Comment: I only included that code inside the CallService method to test it but even if I remove that code when I do the conversion in the Test class it still returns empty.

Comment: @EricBergman You added a comment `Inside this function the InputStream is properly converted to a string.` in the `CallService` method. You can properly read from the `InputStream` only once. Where you do it is up to you.

Comment: And thanks you are right about the naming convention, I was just porting functions from C# to JAVA so I forgot about changing that.

Comment: I understand and I have removed the code that reds the InputString inside the CallService method but still when I read it from the Test class it still converts to an empty string.

Comment: @EricBergman It works for me...Maybe your URL http response just doesn't have a body (unlikely)?  Try cleaning and rebuilding your application. I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: @EricBergman Instead of returning a `Response` object, try returning the `InputStream` directly, just for kicks, to see what happens.

Comment: That didn't work it still returned an empty string when converted.

Comment: @EricBergman So if you read the `InputStream` in the `callService` method, it actually prints out stuff? But if you do it outside, it doesn't? I'm having a hard time believing that :(

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that myself, I have been stuck trying to figure out why this happens with no luck, it doesn't make any sense but yes inside the callService function it does print out the resulted JSON string.

Comment: @Eric I don't know what to tell you. Clean and re-build some more. Update your question if you've changed anything. ??????

Comment: When the InputStream is returned it returns empty, is there some kind of rule that is against returning InputStream or something from a function?

Comment: @EricBergman Not in general. I had originally thought maybe the `InputStream` is lazy loaded and that if the `UrlConnection` object was garbage collected, then the `InputStream` could not be loaded. But I looked at the source and it's eagerly loaded and also that wouldn't explain empty String. Try creating a new project and copy your source over.

Comment: I solved it by first getting the InputStream from HttpURLConnection, then converting it to a byte array, then putting that array into a ByteArrayInputStream. I simply returned the ByteArrayInputStream and everything worked perfectly, I didn't change the Response class since ByteArrayInputStream is a sub class of InputStream, according to the documentation a ByteArrayInpuytStream "Creates a ByteArrayInputStream so that it uses buf as its buffer array. The buffer array is not copied. The initial value of pos is 0 and the initial value of count is the length of buf."